# Add Role in Identity Core Token Response for ASP.NET Core SPA Template

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

So I'm using the **ASP.NET Core React Template with built-in authorization**. In that template, everything is working and I'm able to login and register an account via this

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

When I view the token via application localstorage, I get the following data. Without the role.
[image]

I also viewed the access token via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

My question is, how can I add the role there or the role in the jwt token?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `ProfileService` which implements `IProfileService` interface

I share you code from my project

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        IList<string> roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        var claims = new List<Claim> {
            // here you can include other properties such as id, email, address, etc. as part of the jwt claim types
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.Firstname} {user.Lastname}")
        };
        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            // include the roles
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Add DI registration to **Startup**

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

Details in IdentityServer4 [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html)

Comment: is this automatically added to the token? after I created a `profileservice?`

Comment: "This method is called whenever claims about the user are requested (e.g. during token creation or via the userinfo endpoint)"

Comment: Thanks for this snippet @tmsbrndz, I'm able to see the role, but the `preferred_username` is gone.

Comment: @hikhyper my answer has been improved by mark.. please check it

Comment: Hi @tmsbrndz, have you tried using Policy based authentication with this? I'm having 401 error

Comment: @hikhyper i didn't try yet. Good luck anyway.

Comment: this is actually better placed here:         builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();